# firewall-cmd: You most likely need to use --zone=trusted option

Tags: fedora, firewalld, systemd-networkd

With Fedora 36, I noticed a new firewall-cmd warning I didn't notice before (when setting things up in the same way):

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all        
You're performing an operation over default zone ('public'),
but your connections/interfaces are in zone 'trusted' (see --get-active-zones)
You most likely need to use --zone=trusted option.

public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: http https mosh ssh wireguard
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Besides firewalld that host also runs networkd and wireguard and has 3 interfaces: enp0s3, wg0 and lo

The services are exactly the services I want to be exposed on the public interfaces and which I explicitly configured with firewalld.

The warning reads like all my interfaces are in the trusted zone, but this isn't the case:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
trusted
  interfaces: wg0
```

That means enp0s3 isn't explicitly added to a certain zone and thus is part of the default zone, which should be perfectly fine:

> System administrators assign a zone to a networking interface in its configuration files. If an interface is not assigned to a specific zone, it is assigned to the default zone.

([RHEL 7 Security Guide, Section 5.7.3. Changing the Default Zone](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-working_with_zones#sec-Changing-the-Default-Zone))

Where the default zone is the public zone:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone 
public
```

Thus, my question: Is there a point to this warning?

See also: Networkd Issue: [RFE: setting Zone-parameter in network files for firewalld](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3288)